# How can I programmatically change a sprite's pivot without it affecting a game objects current position and rotation?

Tags: unity

Because of the complexity of positions, I am using the centre pivot for my game objects sprite. Can I possibly change the pivot without it affecting the game objects current position and rotation? or in other words, can I change the pivot while the sprite remains unchanged visibly? I would preferably like to do this using c# script.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the RectTransform used by your sprite? Stretching and non-stretching RectTransform are not handled the same way. [Check this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html)

Comment: If you move the pivot, shouldn't you compensate in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 3):

Of course:

[`RectTransform::pivot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-pivot.html)

> The normalized position in this RectTransform that it rotates around.

Now, if--while changing the pivot--if you don't want it to also move (like what happens in the Unity Editor when you fiddle with the values), you'll have to do some math. Math fortunately Unity has already built in if we don't mind moving between hierarchy transform coordinate systems using `TransformPoint` and `InverseTransformPoint`, rather than working these out for ourselves using a lot of trig (I hate trig and you should too: someone probably already did it).

```
Vector3 GetNewAnchor(RectTransform rt, Vector2 newPivot) {
    Vector3 op = new Vector3(rt.rect.width * newPivot.x - rt.rect.width * rt.pivot.x, rt.rect.height * newPivot.y - rt.rect.height * rt.pivot.y, 0);
    Vector3 pt = rt.TransformPoint(op);
    return rt.parent.InverseTransformPoint(pt);
}
```

What this does is transform a point in local space (the XY position of our new pivot) into world (scene) space and then back down into the local space of the sprite's parent object.

Now you can just do this:

```
RectTransform rt = (RectTransform)sprite.transform;
Vector2 newPiv = new Vector2(0.2f, 0.8f);
Vector3 newAnch = GetNewAnchor(rt, newPiv);
rt.pivot = newPiv;
rt.anchoredPosition = newAnch;
```

Be aware that you need to call `GetNewAnchor` *before* modifying the pivot point.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it included an example of what "some math" might need to be done to adjust the sprite's position.

Comment: @DMGregory I agree, but as I've been on the road since Tuesday, I can't type well (ah, mobile keyboard) and have no ability to double check my work. The primary problem I'd that I am unsure of what happens when the pivot is adjusted during runtime, so I can only speculate.

Comment: @TomTsagk Thanks for the ping, I'd totally forgotten about this question. The problem with pseudo code in this case is that I could be wildly off. I actually have to poke around with it *in Unity* to make sure its right. Getting the `Sin`/`Cos` backwards, using `angle` instead of `-angle`, etc. could all lead to wildly inaccurate results

Comment: @TomTsagk Oh it happens, I did the same thing to someone on Code Golf myself just the other day. You're not wrong though. :)

Comment: @TomTsagk Answer updated. Part way through working out the math I realized, "hold on, Unity has a function for what I'm trying to do."

Answer (score 2):

I made a tool for setting the Sprite pivot points in the editor while maintaining their world positions: https://github.com/thepowerprocess/UnitySpritePivotEditor

[image: Animation of the tool in use]

This is the part where the sprite texture is edited:

```
SpriteRenderer sr = selectedGameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(sr.sprite.texture);
TextureImporter ti = (TextureImporter)AssetImporter.GetAtPath(path);
Vector2 newPivot = new Vector2(childMousePos.x / (sr.sprite.texture.width / sr.sprite.pixelsPerUnit), childMousePos.y / (sr.sprite.texture.height / sr.sprite.pixelsPerUnit)) + ti.spritePivot;
ti.spritePivot = newPivot;
TextureImporterSettings texSettings = new TextureImporterSettings();
ti.ReadTextureSettings(texSettings);
texSettings.spriteAlignment = (int)SpriteAlignment.Custom;
ti.SetTextureSettings(texSettings);
ti.SaveAndReimport();
```

Comment: I noticed that this tool requires Scene View to be in 2D Mode. If it isn't, then it doesn't perform the mouse location raycast correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of unity specific stuff, but what you can do to change the center of rotation of an object is: translate it to the wished origin, rotate it, translate it back. If T is the translation, T' its inverse ("the translation back") and R the rotation, you can then try something like

```
Transform t = T' * R * T;
myObject.transform(t);
```

(Again, this might need to be modified for unity's syntax and depending on whether their matrices are column or row major, feel free to edit to make this more Unity compliant)